# Scientific Linux's scary "Notice to Users"

Tags: linux

While trying Scientific Linux, I found if I enter the "context" menu, and enable the default one during install, then a notice will appear on the login screen:

[image: 000]

[image: 001]

[image: 002]

What is "context" do? By install that my computer will become "the property of US government" and I'll be watched by them thus have no privacy?

Also if I do not enable "context", this notice will not appear, does that mean I'm safe?

Comment: "does that mean I'm safe?" - Safe from what exactly?  Are you simply concerned about the notice?  If you are using your own equipment, you have NOTHING to worry about, the notice is pretty standard on government owned equipment.  It appears you have simply enabled that notice, for whatever reason, the notice is included in the OS itself.  The notice by itself is harmless, it means nothing, unless your actually using US Government owned hardware (which I know is not true in your case).

Comment: Safe from being watched and lose privacy.

Comment: You're fine. Choose an answer if it satisfies you.

Comment: So they will not be able to watch on me, if I install the OS on my own machine, and even with "context" enabled that trigger the notice?

Comment: @Sam No! Nobody is going to watch you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: You're fine as long as it's your personal machine.

I'm not 100% familiar with Scientific Linux, but it seems to be a distribution formerly used exclusively within the U.S. Government.

Context described the use of the system, and the specific goal to be achieved. If it's for a computing goal, you will be giving it a context. If it's not, you will not be giving it a context.

By not enabling "Context", you are perfectly safe.

As long as it is not connected to specifically Fermilab infrastructure to be part of a common goal, you're safe.

Source: [here](http://ftp.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/7/contexts/README.html)

Answer (score 1):

Scientific Linux is made by Fermi Lab, which is a US government lab.  It, therefore, isn't super surprising if it includes a stock warning about using government computers.  If you have installed that on your own computer you're fine.  If you're trying to use a government computer that has it on it and you do not have permission to use that computer, you should stop.